# How do you use comparatives for Japanese adjectives?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, history, comparative-constructions, written-language

I am currently writing a section about the Japanese writing system. I have previously stated that Japanese was originally written completely in Kanji. However, people found it very difficult.

**Therefore, the simpler Hiragana and Katakana was introduced in the ninth century.**

How would I write this sentence in Japanese? If "simpler" was replaced with "simple", I would say:  だから、単純なひらがなとカタカナが九世紀に導入されました.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 「より」 and say 「より単純{たんじゅん}な」 for the comparative form.

(The superlative form is 「最{もっと}も単純な」.)

Nothing to do with your question. but 「だから」 would sound too informal and conversational to be used in that sentence that contains a big word like 「
導入{どうにゅう}」.  I would suggest using 「従{したが}って」 instead.